# Getting HTML Tag

Tags: c#, html

I try to get HTML Data:

I have the html code in a webpage:

```
<a class="hoverunderline commentthread_author_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/KryptonGas" data-miniprofile="83170738">
</a>
```

And I need to get the `data-miniprofile="83170738"` part, But how...?

The URL and ID changes every time.

Sorry for saying, I'm working in C#

Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to do that(untested code):

```
var profile = $(".hoverunderline .commentthread_author_link").data("miniprofile")
```